# How to store data in Mongodb every 24 hours using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I just started working with databases itself and sorry for a dumb question if it.

Problem:
I'm trying to create a system which is going to store the data every 24 hours. I create an API which is taking the exactly data what I need

```
request('GET', 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE')
        .then((r1) => {
            var x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

            var BTCdata = (x1.data.find(d => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.USD.volume_24h);

            console.log(BTCdata);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

    function request(method, url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
            xhr.onload = resolve;
            xhr.onerror = reject;
            xhr.send();
        });
    }
```

And I also create a MongoDB and I can connect to it

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "Link-To-MongoDB";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
    // perform actions on the collection object
    client.close();
});
```

How I can automatically add data to my MongoDB?

Comment: Run a job every 24 hours. You use serveless solution to schedule the job and in that job invoke the api.

Comment: If the solution has to be within a node application, consider using `Agenda` node package which allows you to schedule jobs. doc link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda#example-usage

Comment: @iAviator you mean to invoke script everyday by myself? If yes, then the problem is that I need that script to be invoked everyday in a specific time.

Comment: @planet_hunter It's not necessary to be a node application. It can be anything, but should be working in a final.

Comment: If you already have a box that stays up all the time and can run your script periodically, just set up a cronjob to run your script. `cron` is basically universally available.

Comment: @AKX Thank you for your advice. Currently I just have a script and I also need to somehow add data from api to mongodb. Since i'm just started with databases at all. I'll take a look on cron.

Comment: @Hexycode not invoke manually the job will auto run at specified point of time every day

Comment: @iAviator this is my question how I can insert a data to mongodb every day automatically ?

Comment: Yes, so u need to find the scheduler job providers may be in AWS or Azure which can run the cron/scheduler jobs.

Comment: You can also go for firebase schedule functions.